# robust way to traverse an array

Tags: php, arrays

I had the data in XML file i.e.

```
<domain>  
   <host>xyz</host>  
   <key>keeeeeeeeeey</key>  
</domain>
<domain>
  <host>xyz</host>  
   <key>keeeeeeeeeey</key> 
</domain>
```

From that xml I created an array for robustness had I knew how to find that using xml I would have done so but lack of my knowledge I converted that xml file into array using:

```
 $json = json_encode($xml); 
 $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);`
```

Below is my array:

```
Array
(
    [domain] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [host] => bdbdfbdvbdbdfbdfbf.net
                    [key] => 933f416350de1a955544b30b5bb7ca09cfa2311101a22972320cc4c7af2ecedc03f36b8a48961ef938972478592a1e261819052b51c09a45cf805663f83cb2c0233969255a2c3e2e7e212a295a247b785d41
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [host] => bdev1vvvvvvveinf.net
                    [key] => 933f416350de1a955544b30b5bb7ca09cfa2311101a22972320cc4c7af2ecedc03f36b8a48961ef938972478592a1e261819052b51c09a45cf805663f83cb2c0233969255a2c3e2e7e212a295a247b785d41
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [host] => bdev1.aaaaaaaaureinf.net
                    [key] => 933f416350de1a955544b30b5bb7ca09cfa2311101a22972320cc4c7af2ecedc03f36b8a48961ef938972478592a1e261819052b51c09a45cf805663f83cb2c0233969255a2c3e2e7e212a295a247b785d41
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [host] => bdennnnnnnninf.net
                    [key] => 933f416350de1a955544b30b5bb7ca09cfa2311101a22972320cc4c7af2ecedc03f36b8a48961ef938972478592a1e261819052b51c09a45cf805663f83cb2c0233969255a2c3e2e7e212a295a247b785d41
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [host] => bdeveewerwerwerwerreinf.net
                    [key] => 933f416350de1a955544b30b5bb7ca09cfa2311101a22972320cc4c7af2ecedc03f36b8a48961ef938972478592a1e261819052b51c09a45cf805663f83cb2c0233969255a2c3e2e7e212a295a247b785d41
                )

        )

)
```

I want a robust loop through which if I pass the host name it returns the key. Can anyone please throw some light? The size of the array could grow to 100 000 000 plus entries.

Comment: 1000 entries is nothing really, it's going to be traversed in a few milliseconds on entry-level computers.

Comment: sorry i corrected the figure Millions i wanted to say

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your array to look like:

```
$data = array('domain' => array(
  'bdbdfbdvbdbdfbdfbf.net' => '933...',
  'bdev1vvvvvvveinf.net' => '933...',
));
```

Then you can do this:

```
echo $data['domain']['bdbdfbdvbdbdfbdfbf.net'];
```

There is no "robust" way to do it with your current array. You'd have to search through the entire thing:

```
function get_key($data, $host)
{
    foreach ($data['domain'] as $domain)
    {
      if ($domain['host'] == $host)
        return $domain['key'];
    }
}
```

Given this new information:

> The size of the array could grow to 100 000 000 plus entries.

I retract the usefulness of this answer, as the entire concept of using any plain text format, including XML or a serialized PHP key-value array, to store this amount of data is just crazy.

You should store the data in a database with the domain indexed. Even an sqlite database would be a major upgrade from a linear probe of a text file.

Of course there are ways to store the data in a custom format that is optimized, but there's really no good reason to reinvent something a database can easily do.

Comment: Thanks i have added few more lines on the top of my question the data was in xml and i do not know if there is something which can return the host with key from xml instead of me making an array out of it

Comment: @Mian_Khurram_Ijaz, how often does the data in the XML file change?

Comment: once given a key to the host it will not change for that host

Comment: @Mian_Khurram_Ijaz, I ask because it doesn't seem like you should be using XML to store this data. I don't know who is supplying the XML file, etc, but if you are dealing with millions of records like you say, you should be storing them in a database with an indexed lookup.

Comment: Thanks Matthew , i agree with you and after applying different things i use xPath with SimpleXML to solve the problem. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

If possible, I think it would be better if host could be in place of the array key instead of a numeric index. That means it could look like

```
Array
(
    [domain] => Array
        (
            [bdbdfbdvbdbdfbdfbf.net] => Array
                (

                    [key] => 933f416350de1a955544b30b5bb7ca09cfa2311101a22972320cc4c7af2ecedc03f36b8a48961ef938972478592a1e261819052b51c09a45cf805663f83cb2c0233969255a2c3e2e7e212a295a247b785d41
                )

            [bdev1vvvvvvveinf.net] => Array
                (

                    [key] => 933f416350de1a955544b30b5bb7ca09cfa2311101a22972320cc4c7af2ecedc03f36b8a48961ef938972478592a1e261819052b51c09a45cf805663f83cb2c0233969255a2c3e2e7e212a295a247b785d41
                )

            [bdev1.aaaaaaaaureinf.net] => Array
                (

                    [key] => 933f416350de1a955544b30b5bb7ca09cfa2311101a22972320cc4c7af2ecedc03f36b8a48961ef938972478592a1e261819052b51c09a45cf805663f83cb2c0233969255a2c3e2e7e212a295a247b785d41
                )
       )
)
```

which would be searchable with

```
$somedomain = "bdev1.aaaaaaaaureinf.net";
if (isset($domains['domain'][$somedomain])) {
   // do stuff
   //$domains['domain'][$somedomain]['key']; is the key you want
}
```

If you can, do it that way

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need the [domain] array from the outer array, this should work

```
function getKey($domains)
{
    foreach($domains as $domain)
    {
        if($domain['host'] == $testHost)
           return $domain['key'];
    }
    return false;
}

$myKey = getKey($myArr['domain']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that works with the array that you gave. You don't have to make any changes to the array.

```
/**
 * Find the Key of the Domain in the Array with a Given Host
 * @param $given The host you want to search for
 * @returns The key of the domain (of the array) that has the matching host
 */
function findHost($given)
{
    // This code assumes that the data array is $array .
    global $array;

    foreach ($array["domain"] as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($value["host"] == $given)
            return $key;
    }

    // If no matches
    return false;
}

// Call findHost() as you desire.
// If there is no match, the function returns false.
// Otherwise, it returns the key of $array["domain"] that the host matches.
```

Comment: You reference $array, but it is not defined anywhere.

Comment: @LeviMorrison I mentioned at the first line of code, "This code assumes that the data array is $array ."

Comment: it still won't work, you have to pass the array into the function, or it won't be in scope.

Comment: Thanks for catching my error.  I've fixed the code to factor in the scope of $array.

Comment: Eh, better, but I wouldn't use the global scope :)

Answer (score 0):

With 100 000 000 plus entries you're likely hitting the string length limit in PHP which would mean that you can't use `json_encode` and `json_decode` any longer.

This does something similar, but you need to metric yourself what's faster:

```
$array = (array) $xml;
array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$v) { $v = (array) $v; });
```

Good luck!

Anyway, I wonder how large that XML string is then. Hmm. I think the numbers you give are just not right, your question looks pretty bogus on a second thought.